# Is there any hope that Mathematica answers this parametric integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, integral-equations

Is there any hope that Mathematica answers this integral?

```
Integrate[ Exp[a (b/(c + 2 (1 + x) d)^4 - (e + f/(c + 2 (1 + x) d)^2)^2/(
     4 (2 + x + g)^2))], x]
```

with these assumptions on parameters `a < 0 && b > 0 && d > 0 && e < 0 && f < 0 && g < 0`; the parameter $c\in\mathbb{R}$ can be positive or negative.

$\int  \exp \left(a \left(\frac{b}{(c+2 d (x+1))^4}-\frac{\left(\frac{f}{(c+2 d (x+1))^2}+e\right)^2}{4 (g+x+2)^2}\right)\right) \, dx=?$

---

**P.S.** First, my question was definite integral with the upper and lower limits $\infty$ and $0$; then, I changed to its indefinite form.

Comment: I do not need to go further with its result; I just need its explicit form if possible. As I check even Mathematica does not give answer for a simpler case `Integrate[Exp[-d Sqrt[a + x b + x^2 c]], x]` too

Comment: It results from a statistical physics problem.

Comment: Your changed question is math, not Mathematica (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm for info). Ask it at, for example, at https://math.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3):

Under those conditions the integral diverges and Mathematica shows it by

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]; Integrate[Exp[a (b/(c + 2 (1 + x) d)^4 -
 (e +  f/(c + 2 (1 + x) d)^2)^2/(4 (2 + x + g)^2))], 
{x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> g < 0]
```

> `Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(a (b/(c+<<1>>)^4-(<<1>>)^2/(4 (<<1>>)^2))) does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}.`

Comment: @math2021: You wrote " Is it possible to compute the indefinite integral?". Ask it at math forums as a separate question, for example, at https://math.stackexchange.com/. This is  math, not Mathematica

Answer (score 3):

The limit of the function under integration as `x->∞` is `1` therefore the integral $\int_0^{\infty } f x \, dx$ cannot converge for any choice of variables `a,b,c,d,e,f,g`.

```
Limit[Exp[
  a (b/(c + 2 (1 + x) d)^4 - (e + 
         f/(c + 2 (1 + x) d)^2)^2/(4 (2 + x + g)^2))], 
 x -> ∞]
```

---

1

Comment: @math2021: Your integral diverges for any assumptions. If the limit of the function exists it must be zero for an improper integral to converge.